# What component is this twin-transistor schematic symbol?

Tags: identification, schematics

While reading Jay Carlson's article on [embedded Linux processors](https://jaycarlson.net/embedded-linux/#sam9x60), I saw this schematic on the site:

[image: SAM9X60 Schematic]

I don't recognize the components in the Q1 and Q2 sections. I think it's some sort of transistor, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: It looks something like [one of these](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TC6321-N-P-Channel-Enhancement-Mode-MOSFET-Pair-DS20005724B.pdf)

Comment: These function just like an H-bridge in a switch mode power supply.  Just replace the speaker with the primary of the transformer.  Only with two complimentary transistors in a package, instead of 4 separate transistors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Q1 and Q2 are dual, complementary (n-channel and p-channel), power MOSFETs; two transistors in one package.

If you call the two FETs in each symbol u and d (for up and down), then the circuit action is like this:

First, Q1u and Q2d are turned on.  This creates a current path from Vdd through the speaker from top to bottom, to GND.  You cut off the bottom of the schematic, but GND is a reasonable assumption.

Next, those two transistors are turned off, and Q1d and Q2u are turned on.  This creates a current path from Vdd through the speaker from bottom to top, to GND.

The effect is that the speaker "sees" a peak-to-peak driving waveform of 2 x Vdd.  The term for this is BTL - Bridge-Tied Load.  It is a way to get more power into a speaker without increasing the available power supply voltage.

Comment: It's also convinient as you don't need to have a split rail supply or use a large capacitor to AC couple the speaker.